# WPF ComboBox Style Missing

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

This may be my ignorance but I'm having an issue with the style of my Combo Box disappearing at run time but not in the editor. I have:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DropDownSelectTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cb"  
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource HookCollection}, Path=Collect }" 
                      DisplayMemberPath="Device" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=HookCollection.SelectedItem}" 
                      >

            </ComboBox>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tb" Foreground="#858585" IsHitTestVisible="False" Padding="4,1,0,0" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Italic>Select A Device</Italic>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger SourceName="cb" Property="SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </Trigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

With...

```
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource DropDownSelectTemplate}" Margin="5,0" Height="20" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Panel.ZIndex="1" />
```

My goal: Have a databinded combo box. I'm not asking for much...

My result:

[image: ComboBox Missing Style... why?]

So, what can I do to keep the default style, or, at maximum be able to change the settings of the text display of the combo box but not get rid of the background, window effect and more.

Comment: Have you applied some style on comboBox?

Comment: I don't think so. Unless what's above is not the only place I can enter in a style. I don't have any code behind referring to it...

Comment: There might be some default style declared for ComboBox under your window resources or app resources. Posted code seems fine to me.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll look elsewhere. I didn't notice anything abnormal, but, your probably correct since I can't find anything wrong there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a background for the combobox and/or textblock(s).  Add

```
 background="#FFFFFF"
```

into both (in the Xaml) and then see what happens.  If it comes out with a white background then great